# XP to 14.04 migration

Tags: windows-xp, migration

my puter: 2.3 ghz sempron, 4 g ram, 500gb hd, nvidia 6100 nforce405 chipset/gt240 gc, win xp. I want to know if i can run 14.04 64 bit ubuntu.

Comment: This question [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) should have the answer to your question on minimum software requirements. To find whether it can run 64bit, you can check the architecture of XP install as shown [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows#1TC=windows-7).

Answer (score 0):

It can run Lubuntu, Xubuntu and 14.10 Ubuntu MATE.
These are variations of Ubunut, with different (and lighter) [Desktop environments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment).